# Personal Blog not sending notifications on comments from users?

Tags: 2013, alert, blog, newsfeed

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I'm talking about the regular "Blog" each user can have on his/her MySite if activated.

When commenting is enabled and other users comment on blog posts, the author does not get an e-mail, nor does the comment appear in the Newsfeed.

Yes, a custom alert could be set up on the "Comments" list within the Blog web, but that is a manual process. **Is there an automatic process so that the author of blog posts is automatically notified of comments?**

Comment: Setting an alert on comments worked like a charm - thanks!

Comment: In my case, I need to email the blog author when a comment is posted. This is not possible by configuring alert in Comments list. But possible using event receiver. The alternative method that I tried is creating a simple workflow to send email. You can get post id and post url in the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create an Event Receiver for the blog template and use Feature Stapling so that the event receiver would attach to the template of the blog site. It needs to use `SPUtility.SendEmail` to send out, to the Blog Owner, and email upon new comment.

*References:*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx
http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2013/04/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint.html

---

**Edit:** Another OOTB solution is to just to **set an alert** on the `Comments` list in which comments are stored in a Blog.

Comment: So this is definitely non-standard? You won't get any notifications on n ew comments? Sure, event receiver is always an option.

Comment: It's not standard to have new comments email blog owners OOTB, no.

Comment: Pretty stupid... That way a blog owner would have to check for comments manually all the time as there is no "comment feed".

Comment: Not completely correct Mike: Comments are actually saved in a comments list. One can just set up alerts for that list and we're good to go.

Comment: That's correct. Maybe I didn't specify that correctly. What I meant was that alerts are not *automatically* turned on upon blog creation to email the blog owner when a comment is created..